# Powershell/CMD highlight to right-click copy in vista

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, powershell

On my XP machine using powershell (Powershell prompt here), I can highlight text with mouse+leftclick and then copy the highlighted text to clipboard by clicking right-click. (Same with CMD)

How can I get the same functionality in vista?

(may be I installed some helper tool in xp that I'm not aware of?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the system menu (the icon in the upper left) - choose Defaults. Under options, check QuickEdit mode.

Comment: And set this to the default for all command windows when it asks.